# How best to set a comparison table in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

I want to make a `frame` in `beamer` that compares two thingys according to 4-5 parameters, uncovered sequentially. My modest efforts to get something pleasing to the eye using `\begin{columns}` and `<1->`-type things have floundered. Do you know of a nice way to do such a thing?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It's really not easy to understand your problem just based on a description.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is by using a `tabular` environment and using the `\pause` command to step through the table.

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}
  Thingy 1 &Thingy 2 \\ \pause
  Param 1  &Param 1  \\ \pause
  Param 2  &Param 2  \\
\end{tabular}
```

This snippet provides a crude start since I do not know how much text you need for each parameter. It should be relatively simple to adjust the tabular environment to your needs.

Comment: I ended up using the columns environment, but maybe I'll give this a try next time. Thanks!